# What's the best way to add a default admin user in express/mongoose app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

What's the best way to add a default admin user in express/mongoose app?

Answer (score 0):

If you'r using Mongo Atlas, you can go into your dashboard for your database and then go to "Database Access" then click add new database user, whence you can make that user a admin. Photo Below
[image: Admin user]